# transparent Statusbar and ActionBar on SDK < 19

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-statusbar

can we have Transparent status bar and ActionBAr on SDK < 19 ? am able to get this on SDK >= 19 by using this Code :

for statusbar :

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

for ActionBAr :

```
setTitle("");
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF")));
actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF")));
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

any idea how to get this programmatically ??

Comment: no you cant have transparent status bar below 19

Comment: semi transparent ? with vibrancy ? @ankitagrawal

Comment: nope nothing you cannot do anything with status bar in less than 19

Comment: btw that statusbar code is 21 plus not 19 plus